# To calculate power of a number using call by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void power(int *x,int *y);
 
int main()

{

    int m,n;
    printf("Enter the number and power :-");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    power(&m,&n);
    
}

void power(int* x, int* y)

{

    int i,result=1;
    if(*y==0)
        printf("The result = 1");
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<*y; i++)
        {
            result *= (*x);
        }
        printf("The result of %d^%d = %d",*x,*y,result);
    }
}
```

The result of 10^10 comes out to be 1410065408 I don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Have you tried running your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables? If not, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: you have an overflow, replace `int` by `long long` or `int64_t` to be sure and you will have the right result

Comment: 10^10 does not fit the 32-bit `int` variable.

Comment: On most platforms, [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) is defined as 2.1 billion, which is 9 decimal places. This means that an `int` can represent a number between `-2,147,483,648` and `+2,147,483,647`. The result of your mathematical operation falls outside that range.

Comment: Ignoring UB from overflow ... `(10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10) % (2^32) = 1410065408` ==> `10^10 = 2*4294967296 + 1410065408`

Comment: In C, there is no such thing as *call by reference*.

Answer (score 2):

you visibly have an overflow, probably your `int`are on 32bits

using `long long` :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void power(long long *x,long long *y);
 
int main()

{

    long long m,n;
    printf("Enter the number and power :-");
    scanf("%lld%lld",&m,&n);
    power(&m,&n);
    
}

void power(long long* x, long long* y)

{

    long long i,result=1;
    if(*y==0)
        printf("The result = 1");
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<*y; i++)
        {
            result *= (*x);
        }
        printf("The result of %lld^%lld = %lld",*x,*y,result);
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number and power :-10 10
The result of 10^10 = 10000000000pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

To be sure to use 64b int you can use `int64_t`

Comment: I guess you don't need to use `long long` to pass the base & the power. Using an integer here will be memory saving.

Comment: @RohanBari I admit I did a lazy global change, anyway the OP using big numbers  the base can need a long long already without producing overflow because power enough small, and why not having the base 0 and a power requiring a long long too ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `int` for the result, and it doesn't fit.  You need to use `long`.  The size of `int` is 32 bits which has a max signed value of 2147483647.

Comment: Yes, but `long` might be 32 bits too: use `long long`.

Comment: @WeatherVane is correct. For example, on the Microsoft Windows platform, a `long` is 32 bits, not 64.

Comment: 32 bits is the *minimum* guaranteed size of `long`.

Comment: Thanks!  I wish it were a 930!  It's a 1986 Carrera with the 3.2L.

Comment: @rallen911 ah, a turbo look then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your given program uses 4-bytes integer which is capable to hold the values between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 but 10^10 is too large to hold it.

Taking the appropriate type (such as `long long`) to hold such large outcome will easily solve your issue (notice the comments as an explanation to the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// The function signature
void power(int *x, int *y);

int main(void) {
    int bs, pw;
    
    printf("Enter the value of base and power: ");

    // Verifying the inputs
    if (scanf("%d%d", &bs, &pw) != 2)
        // If the values were incorrectly entered, then it returns
        // with an error code without further actions
        return 1;
        
    power(&bs, &pw);
    
    return 0;
}

// The function definition    
void power(int *x, int *y) {
    long long result = 1;

    // Dereferencing and using assignment operator for self-multiplication with
    // the dereferenced 'x'
    for (int i = 0; i < *y; i++)
        result *= *x;
    
    printf("Results: %lld\n", result);
}
```

---

**A sample test case:**

```
Enter the value of base and power: 10 10
Results: 10000000000
```

Works on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/rkyld-7MP) as well.